Ignore all html template errors in a module
I am in the middle of a giant refactor and at the moment it would be really nice to have angular ignore all template errors.
I have tried this in my main module with no luck:
@NgModule({
...
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
...
})

Any ideas?

try adding the same to every module present!

If there's no configuration for it, one hack could be changing these occurrences in angular itself: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aangular+NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA.name&type=code

@NarenMurali only have 2 modules, its in both.

@tevemadar really, that stinks?  what is the purpose of settings the schemas then?

@lostintranslation in tsconfig.json you will see compiler options where you set angular specific errors, try disabling them, maybe it will get rid of the errors!

@lostintranslation no, I just misinterpreted the question completely. I thought you actually need NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to be present, and potentially in dozens of modules. ¯\(ツ)/¯
